# MDS stored procedure

Tags: sql, mds

I am working on stored procedures in SQL for master data services.I want to create a stored procedure for slowly changing dimension 2 concept. Can someone pls explain me about @memberIdlist?Moreover can someone explain me about how to update on a join statement?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**@MemberIdList** is a Table-Valued Parameter of User Defined Table Type **mdm.MemberId**.

You can see type definition under Programability-Types-UserDefinedTableTypes hierarchy in Management Studio.

---

For updating table on a join-based statement You must specify which table you need to update, for example:

```
update tab_one
   set fieldname = 10
from
   dwh.table_one tab_one
   inner join dwh.table_two tab_two on
      tab_two.key = tab_one.key
```